# How to get a cell to display a value from one column when the values of another column go above a certain number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am doing a breakeven analysis and want to know what formula i can type into excel so that once my income column reaches my breakeven point it shows what date that breakeven point was hit. The dates are in an adjacent column

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing or tutor service. [Edit] your question to include what have you tried and where you have gotten stuck. It would be helpful to see some sort of example of how your data is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use the "IF" function. Try it in a third column and (say the original columns are A and B and your breakeven value is 10) with the syntax ; =IF(Bn>=10 "REACHED" 0), this should give you in the third column 0 everywhere until the breakeven point. You can make it even more complex, use the examples in "help" or the forums.